# Write status in datagrid column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple WPF application which populates rows with data collected from binded list and it looks like this:
[image]

Now as you can see my first column is empty but I want to write down information that is depending on the `sts` column. For example: if `sts == 8` I want to write down letter R in that first blank column and leave it blank when `sts == 0`. How can I do this?
Here is a backcode for my WPF:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="White" Height="316" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="640" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Oblista}" AutoGeneratingColumn="generiseColumn" >
<!---->
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
            <EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonDown" Handler="Row_RightCLick"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="sts" Width="50" Binding="{Binding cflag}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adresa"  Width="80" Binding="{Binding Sadr_reg}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Opis" Width="200" Binding="{Binding naziv}"/> 
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tip" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Stip_reg}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vrednost" Width="80" Binding="{Binding sVal}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min" Width="40" Binding="{Binding lo_limit}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Max" Width="40" Binding="{Binding hi_limit}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rw" Width="40" Binding="{Binding write}"/> 
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

XAML.CS:

```
 public  BindingList<PIO_CARD> Oblista = new BindingList<PIO_CARD>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = Oblista; 
}
```

Comment: Why not doing this in the viewmodel and adding a new property to the list you're binding your grid to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the empty `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that has a `CellTemplate` with a `DataTrigger`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding cflag}" Value="8">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="R" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or you could add another property to your `PIO_CARD` class and bind to this one:

```
public string FirstValue
{
    get { return cflag == "8" ? "R" : string.Empty; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstValue}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either write a `DataTrigger` or you can extend your `PIO_CARD` class and add a property where you can bind the first column to:

```
public class ExtendedPIO_CARD : PIO_CARD
{
    public string FirstColumn
    {
        get
        {

            if (cflag == 8)
            {
                return "R";
            }
            if(cflag == 0)
            {
                return  string.Empty;
            }

            return "default";
        }
    } 
}
```